# Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached with angular-meteor in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular-filters, angular-meteor

**This is the template:**

```
<span class="sitename">{{ hack|getTitle }}</span>
```

I set a filter `getTitle`:

**angular-filter.js:**

```
angular.module('mgod')
    .filter('getTitle', ['$meteor', function($meteor) {
        return function(input) {
            var result = $meteor.object(Site, {
                '_id': input.site_id
            }, {
                'title': 1
            });
            $meteor.subscribe('siteTitle');
            return result.title;
        };
    }]);
```

**publish in Meteor:**

```
Meteor.publish('siteTitle', function() {
    var result = Site.find({});
    return result;
});
```

**But Chrome throws this error:**

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>       Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function (){    // 145\n
>       return _.omit(data, data.$$internalProps);           // 146\n        }","newVal":{"_id":{"_str":"55b1b3bb0060250cd1535c62"},"domain":"nnland.gov.cn","icp_id":"532be6aaa48e4c7c6709851a","title":"南宁市国土资源局门户网","scan_time":"2015-07-23","ip":"180.141.91.32","level":2,"location":{"province":"广西壮族自治区","city":"南宁市"},"geo":

How can I fix it?

Comment: Always check whether `input` exists before doing anything with it in your filter functions. It can take little time before containing a real value.

Comment: @BraveKenny Sorry I don't konw what you mean```